# Watch folder with VLC

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player, playlists, smart-playlist

I love VLC but would love it even more if I could get the media library to watch a folder so it updates when new movies download. Is there a way to do this?

I'm on a mac.

Comment: May I recommend taking to the VLC forums for this, the answer may much quicker than here.

Comment: I would, but the VLC forum is such a hideously designed mess that it is impossible to find any information there.

Comment: You should just code the feature yourself

Answer (score 0):

At least in the Windows version of VLC you can play a folder. And it will automatically detect new files on file change.

To open a directory use either the menu **Media -> open folder** 
or the Shortcut. On windows it's **Ctrl+F**

Comment: I just tried "Open Folder" with VLC 2.2.6 for Windows, and it didn't detect when files were added to the folder. Is there a trick to making it work?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a tiny open-source app for macOS and Windows called [VLC Scheduler](https://github.com/EugeneDae/VLC-Scheduler) which does exactly that. It watches the folders specified in its configuration file (vlcscheduler.yaml) for new media files and adds them to VLC. Minimal configuration for macOS:

```
sources:
    - path: /Users/<username>/Movies/VLC/
```